# Sorting data in List by specific value

Tags: java, android, list, sorting, android-asynctask

I have an issue where my recyclerview adds new items at the end, whereas I want the latest items at the top upon user refresh. I've been scratching around all over the net and it essentially boils down to adding setreverseLayout or setStackFromEnd. This gives other complications such as the recycler view not scrolling to the top to the latest item.

I then had a thought of maybe ordering my data list by a specific value and then it should return it as I want it. Can this be done and would it resolve my issue? I want to sort it by value adopt_rownum desc.

> My Custom Adapter

```
package com.example.admin.paws;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by admin on 9/16/2016.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public Context context;
    public List<MyData> my_data;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<MyData> my_data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.my_data = my_data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardnew,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String name = my_data.get(position).getName();
        String age = my_data.get(position).getAge();
        String gender = my_data.get(position).getGender();
        String SubstAge = age.substring(0,age.indexOf("(") -1);
        String NameAgeGender = name + ", " + SubstAge + ", " + gender;

           holder.about.setText(my_data.get(position).getAbout());
        holder.NameAgeGender.setText(NameAgeGender);
        Glide.with(context).load(my_data.get(position).getPhoto_path()).into(holder.photo_path);

        //activity_card_details vars
       // final String about = my_data.get(position).getAbout();
        final String adoptId = my_data.get(position).getId()+"";
        final String photo_path_dtls = my_data.get(position).getPhoto_path();
        final String listedDate = my_data.get(position).getDatetime_listed();
        final String status = my_data.get(position).getStatus();
        final String breed = my_data.get(position).getBreed();
        final String source = my_data.get(position).getSource();
        final String contact_info = my_data.get(position).getContact_info();
        final String suburb = my_data.get(position).getSuburb();
        final String city = my_data.get(position).getCity();
        final String province = my_data.get(position).getProvince();
        final String concat_location = suburb + ", " + city + ", " + province;
        final String viewCounter = my_data.get(position).getViewCounter()+"";

//When click on photo
        holder.photo_path.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,CardDetailsActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra("listedDate",listedDate);
                intent.putExtra("adoptId",adoptId);
              //  intent.putExtra("about",about);
                intent.putExtra("status",status);
                intent.putExtra("breed",breed);
                intent.putExtra("source",source);
                intent.putExtra("contactinfo",contact_info);
                intent.putExtra("location",concat_location);
                intent.putExtra("photo_path_dtls",photo_path_dtls);
                intent.putExtra("viewCounter",viewCounter);


                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return my_data.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

        public TextView NameAgeGender;
        public ImageView photo_path;
        public TextView about;

        private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            about = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.about);
            NameAgeGender = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameAgeGender);
          //  NameAgeGender.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9C9393"));
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Lato-Medium.ttf");
            NameAgeGender.setTypeface(typeface);
            //NameAgeGender.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F35959"));
            photo_path = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo_path);
        }

    }
}
```

> My DataList

```
package com.example.admin.paws;

public class MyData {
//the must be in the same order of the select column order
    public int adopt_rownum
            ,viewCounter
            ,adopt_id;

    private String
             name
            ,type
            ,breed
            ,age
            ,gender
            ,size
            ,about
            ,photo_path
            ,source
            ,contact_info
            ,suburb
            ,city
            ,province
            ,datetime_listed
            ,status;

    public MyData(
            int adopt_rownum,
            int viewCounter,
            int adopt_id,
            String name,
            String type,
            String breed,
            String age,
            String gender,
            String size,
            String about,
            String photo_path,
            String source,
            String contact_info,
            String suburb,
            String city,
            String province,
            String datetime_listed,
            String status)
    {
     this.adopt_rownum = adopt_rownum;
     this.viewCounter = viewCounter;
     this.adopt_id = adopt_id;
     this.name = name;
     this.type = type;
     this.breed = breed;
     this.age = age;
     this.gender = gender;
     this.size = size;
     this.about = about;
     this.photo_path = photo_path;
     this.source = source;
     this.contact_info = contact_info;
     this.suburb = suburb;
     this.city = city;
     this.province = province;
     this.datetime_listed = datetime_listed;
     this.status = status;
    }

    //adopt_rownum used for filtering the records.
    public int getAdopt_rownum() {
        return adopt_rownum;
    }

    //viewcounter
    public int getViewCounter() {
        return viewCounter;
    }

    //adopt_id
    public int getId() {
        return adopt_id;
    }

    public void setId(int adopt_id) {
        this.adopt_id = adopt_id;
    }

    //name
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    //type
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    //breed
    public String getBreed() {
        return breed;
    }

    public void setBreed(String breed) {
        this.breed = breed;
    }

    //age
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    //gender
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.age = gender;
    }

    //size
    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    //about
    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public void setAbout(String about) {
        this.about = about;
    }

    //photo path
    public String getPhoto_path() {
        return photo_path;
    }

    public void setPhoto_path(String photo_path) {
        this.photo_path = photo_path;
    }

    //source
    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    //contact_info
    public String getContact_info() {
        return contact_info;
    }

    public void setContact_info(String contact_info) {
        this.contact_info = contact_info;
    }

    //suburb
    public String getSuburb() {
        return suburb;
    }

    public void setSuburb(String suburb) {
        this.contact_info = suburb;
    }

    //city
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    //province
    public String getProvince() {
        return province;
    }

    public void setProvince(String province) {
        this.province = province;
    }

    //datetime_listed
    public String getDatetime_listed() {
        return datetime_listed;
    }

    public void setDatetime_listed(String datetime_listed) {
        this.datetime_listed = datetime_listed;
    }

    //status
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }


}
```

> The fragment that displays the results. Another question on the side, inside this fragment for load_data_from_server its giving me a warning that "This Async task should be static or leaks might occur". I have no idea what this means since I'm completely new to JAVA.

```
package com.example.admin.paws;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link feedFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link feedFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class feedFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    public Activity FragActivity;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private List<MyData> data_list;
    private CustomAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public String EndOfFeed;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public feedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment fragment_feed.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static feedFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        feedFragment fragment = new feedFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        final GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.feedRefresh);

       TextView tvEndOfFeed = rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvEndOfFeed);
       tvEndOfFeed.setText(EndOfFeed);

        //recycler view
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        data_list = new ArrayList<>();
        load_data_from_server(0, "getFeed.php");

        gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 1); //2 nr of cards next to each other
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        //gridLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);

        adapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), data_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

               if (gridLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == data_list.size() - 1) {
                    load_data_from_server(data_list.get(data_list.size() - 1).getAdopt_rownum(), "getFeed.php");
                }
            }
        });

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                //this works but issue with the ordering of the adoptrownum
               load_data_from_server(data_list.get(data_list.size() -1).getAdopt_rownum(), "refreshFeed.php");

                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    private void load_data_from_server(final int adopt_id, final String phpScript) {

        AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://10.0.2.2/app_scripts/"+phpScript+"?adopt_rownum="+integers[0])
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

                    for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        MyData data = new MyData(
                                object.getInt("ADOPT_ROWNUM"),
                                object.getInt("VIEWCOUNTER"),
                                object.getInt("ADOPT_ID"),
                                object.getString("NAME"),
                                object.getString("TYPE"),
                                object.getString("BREED"),
                                object.getString("AGE"),
                                object.getString("GENDER"),
                                object.getString("SIZE"),
                                object.getString("ABOUT"),
                                object.getString("PHOTO_PATH"),
                                object.getString("SOURCE"),
                                object.getString("CONTACT_INFO"),
                                object.getString("SUBURB"),
                                object.getString("CITY"),
                                object.getString("PROVINCE"),
                                object.getString("DATETIME_LISTED"),
                                object.getString("STATUS")
                        );
                        data_list.add(data);
                    }



                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.println("End of content"+e);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        task.execute(adopt_id);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


}
```

> I added the Comparator as instructed below but the output is a bit weird...

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyData > {
    @Override
    public int compare(final MyData o1, final MyData o2) {
        Log.d("APP", "compare Starting... ");
        Integer val1 = o1.getAdopt_rownum();
        Log.d("APP", "compare val1... "+val1);
        Integer val2 = o2.getAdopt_rownum();
        Log.d("APP", "compare val1... "+val2);
        Log.d("APP", "compare val1 and val2 ="+val1.compareTo(val2));
        return val1.compareTo(val2);
    }
}

output
compare Starting... 
compare val1... 2
compare val2... 1
compare val1 and val2 =1
...
compare Starting... 
compare val1... 14
compare val2... 15
compare val2 and val2 =1
```

> Below is how i implemented it in my fragment

```
private void load_data_from_server(final int adopt_id, final String phpScript) {

AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://10.0.2.2/app_scripts/"+phpScript+"?adopt_rownum="+integers[0])
                .build();
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().string());

            for (int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){

                JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                MyData data = new MyData(
                        object.getInt("ADOPT_ROWNUM"),
                        object.getInt("VIEWCOUNTER"),
                        object.getInt("ADOPT_ID"),
                        object.getString("NAME"),
                        object.getString("TYPE"),
                        object.getString("BREED"),
                        object.getString("AGE"),
                        object.getString("GENDER"),
                        object.getString("SIZE"),
                        object.getString("ABOUT"),
                        object.getString("PHOTO_PATH"),
                        object.getString("SOURCE"),
                        object.getString("CONTACT_INFO"),
                        object.getString("SUBURB"),
                        object.getString("CITY"),
                        object.getString("PROVINCE"),
                        object.getString("DATETIME_LISTED"),
                        object.getString("STATUS")
                );
                data_list.add(data);

                **Collections.sort(data_list,new MyComparator());**
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            //System.out.println("End of content"+e);
            EndOfFeed = e+"";
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

task.execute(adopt_id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort list by a property using the following code:

```
Collections.sort(myList, new MyComparator());

public static class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyData > {
    @Override
    public int compare(final MyData o1, final MyData o2) {
        return o1.getAdoptRownum().compareTo(o2.getAdoptRownum());
    }
}
```

I usually declare comparators inside the relevant POJO class. Then you can call `Collections.sort` whenever you refresh your data.

Comment: To build on this answer, you could do ```MyComparator implements Comparator<MyData>``` or you can execute this logic in a lambda expression....```myData.sorted((o1, o2) -> o1.getAdoptRownum().compareTo(o2.getAdoptRownum())).collect(Collectors.toList());``` Note: Java 8 requred for java.util.Stream

Comment: @Neria I followed the instructions but not getting the correct output in the Comparator. Please see my edited post with what I implemented.

Comment: @Neria how does the sorter know what to sort by if the comparator just returns 1 all the time?

Comment: @DeanLambrechts `Comparator` returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second. The returned value is not your concern, just make sure that the boolean expression is correct.

Comment: @Neria it worked thanks, but seems like its in asc order, whereas I want it in desc order.

Comment: @Neria nevermind. I just did the below.
Collections.sort(data_list,new MyComparator().reversed());